Springboot connect Kafka get error "No resolvable bootstrap urls given in bootstrap.servers"
I have a springboot project and try to connect Kafka. My Kafka server is started on CentOS7 instead of docker.
And then, the program got error said:
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: No resolvable bootstrap urls given in bootstrap.servers
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.parseAndValidateAddresses(ClientUtils.java:89) ~[kafka-clients-2.6.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.parseAndValidateAddresses(ClientUtils.java:48) ~[kafka-clients-2.6.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:734) ~[kafka-clients-2.6.0.jar:na]
    ... 30 common frames omitted

It looks like a problem aboud Kafka server url. However, this url can be connected. And the port 9092 is opened on firewall. The telnet can connect this url. Here is my application.yml.
spring:
  kafka:
    bootstrap-servers: 192.168.1.101:9092
    consumer:
      group-id: get-seeta-id
      auto-offset-reset: earliest
      key-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
      value-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer

Here is my configuration of Kafka server server.properties:
broker.id=0
port=9092
host.name=192.168.1.101
log.dirs=/data/kafka/kafka_data/log/kafka
zookeeper.connect=192.168.1.101:2181
listeners=PLAINTEXT://192.168.1.101:9092

Could you please help me solve this problem? Thanks~

The host.name  property shouldn't be needed. Have you also tried setting advertised.listeners?

yes, I set advertised.listeners in server.properties and the host name is the same.

If you've set it, please [edit] your question to include it. Also, telnet isn't how to fully test the configuration is correct. You can Install and use kcat -L for that
